# DocuSign: Is using X-DocuSign-Authentication in the header for calling API's safe?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Docusign for embedded signing in my web application. In my case

I am not expecting users to have Docusign account and that's why i am using `X-DocuSign-Authentication` in the header for calling the API's and generating the url for e-signing.

Is this process safe to use on production?

Answer (score 3):

Passing 'X-DocuSign-Authentication' wouldn't be considered safe, therefore we recommend to use oauth in production accounts:
https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt

Comment: But in my case i cant use Oauth since oauth requires users to have a Docusign account.

Comment: So does legacy auth. If you want your app to obtain an access token by itself (the user is a signer and doesn't have a DocuSign account) then use OAuth JWT grant

Answer (score 1):

X-DocuSign-Authentication is not 'safe' because it requires your application to handle plaintext credentials directly.

For a 'service' application that accountless users interact with, JWT authentication is likely an appropriate replacement: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/

Comment: But i don't want to redirect the user(student in my case) to a different page and ask for allowing the creation of envelope. This wont be user friendly.

Comment: If you use JWT grant then you DO NOT need to use any redirects. Your app, by itself, obtains the access token. User does nothing.

Comment: To expand on Larry's comment, the Redirect portion happens during the consent grant which happens once during the setup phase. Once the key is authorized to act as the user, it can do so fully "behind the scenes" with no further user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR:

`X-DocuSign-Authentication` is no longer supported or allowed for new DocuSign REST API applications. And if you're using it for an existing application then you must upgrade to OAuth.

---

`X-DocuSign-Authentication` is no longer supported or allowed for new DocuSign REST API applications.

There is a depreciation schedule for existing API applications that use this authentication type.